# Unable to Switch back to running desktop mode from TTY in 18.04

Tags: command-line, drivers, 18.04, apt, grub2

Tried following thing but did not work. Any help is highly appreciated.

Ctrl+Alt+F7

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I think it is necessary to add a little more information to your question so we can help. Did you remove your display manager as you tried to reinstall ubuntu-desktop? Try running `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` to see if it gives you any output

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to late. If I understand correctly, what you met is not a terminal.
In this Ubuntu version, if you didn't switch, the tty2 should hold your running one, but tty7 is nothing.

This is because the default display manager of 18.04 is SDDM, which just have 6 initial ttys(tty1~tty6). So, if you did something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, the traditional place of a GUI tty, there is no terminal(no tty7), but something else(maybe fcsk?), so the commands don't work.

Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx (x is 1~6)</kbd> and back to a used tty, especially <kbd>F2</kbd> to your desktop.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read and comments. The problem was solved. Just reinstalled it.